# Webscraping: Get Link that is only visible on the website not in the html

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, nightmare

So I'm on a website and I want to get a link. The link I want to get is shown on the website, but is not visible in the html file. There is a copy button which copies the link to your clipboard. I want to get the link, does someone know how i can get it?
The html looks like that:

```
<div class="containerInvite">
      <div class="title">Invite your friends!</div>
      <div class="inviteBar">
        <input type="text" readonly id="invite">  --Here should be the link
        <button class="button btn btn-primary" 
         id="inviteCopyButton">Copy</button> --The Button that copies the link
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you share the website so that i can get more insights for solution?

Comment: @SmashGuy the website is https://skribbl.io. On that site you have to click on the "Create Private Room" Button then you see the link I want to get.

Comment: The problem here is the url will not be present in the html and it is getting generated dynamically while you press `Create Private Room`. I tried tracing that but failed because of lack of time. It seems something complicated. Good luck with it.

Comment: @SmashGuy Ok. Thank you for trying.

Answer (score 0):

to just read the value of `id="invite"` input from javascript, use:

```
document.getElementById("invite").value;
```

if you want the button to copy the value into clipboard, make a function

```
function copyLink() {
  //Get the text field
  var copyText = document.getElementById("invite");
  //Select the text field
  copyText.select();
  //Copy the text inside the text field
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

then add

```
onclick="copyLink()"
```

in your button. or attach a "click" event

Comment: that's not really what I want to do. The value of the invite field is null. The copy button already exists, I want to get the value it copies to the clipboard with webscraping.

Comment: that's not a link. that's javascript triggered by DOM event.